# lxml not parsing unicode properly for HTML

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

I am trying to parse HTML, but unfortunately `lxml` is not allowing me to grab the actual text:

```
node = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
self.fingerprint['Title'] = node.cssselect('.document-title div')[0].text
print '@@####', self.fingerprint['Title']

# @@#### DÃ©mineurs
```

What do I need to do to correctly parse this text? Here is the web page: https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/D%C3%A9mineurs?id=KChu8wf5eVo&hl=fr and the text should be Démineurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an encoding issue.

It looks like you're using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which is good, because it does this work for you.

First, [requests guesses at the encoding](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content), which you can access with `r.encoding`.  For that page, requests guessed at utf-8.

You *could* do:

```
data = r.content.decode('UTF-8')
# or
data = r.content.decode(r.encoding)
# then
node = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
self.fingerprint['Title'] = node.cssselect('.document-title div')[0].text
print '@@####', self.fingerprint['Title']
```

which works:

```
@@#### Démineurs
```

**But better yet**, just use the `text` attribute, which has the output already decoded correctly.

```
node = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
self.fingerprint['Title'] = node.cssselect('.document-title div')[0].text
print '@@####', self.fingerprint['Title']
```

works:

```
@@#### Démineurs
```

Comment: What's the difference between `r.text` and `r.content` ?

Comment: @Hockey127 requests stores the raw output in `content` it also "makes an educated guess" about the encoding and decodes the output, storing it in `text`.  You almost always want `text`.

Comment: @jedwards: the educated guess comes down to: parse the `content-type` header for a `charset` parameter. If missing and the mime-type is `text/*`, use Latin-1, otherwise use `chardet` to guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hmm sounds like it relies on appropriate webserver configuration pretty heavily.  Allowing the webserver (apache, at least) to provide the wrong charset can be pretty easy.  I can't make up my mind whether this is a drawback or appropriately sufficient guesswork.

Comment: @jedwards: which is why I recommend to ignore the charset from the server and use BeautifulSoup's detection (which'll pick up a HTML `<meta>` header if present).

Answer (score 7):

The document has no encoding information, therefore you need to create a parser that uses the correct encoding by default.

```
>>> lxml.html.fromstring('<p>é</p>').text
u'\xc3\xa9'
>>> hp = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
>>> lxml.html.fromstring('<p>é</p>', parser=hp).text
u'\xe9'
```